# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: X509 KeyManagerFactory not available

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography

I want to create SSL connection. I created keystore. and trying to use x509.

```
 final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
```

but I am getting below exception on console after running.

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: X509 KeyManagerFactory not available
>       at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)                    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance(connectionType);
>               final char[] keyPassPhrase = "changeit".toCharArray();
>               //String [] array  = Security.getProviders();
>               final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");

```
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("ClientKeyStore"), keyPassPhrase);
        provider();
        final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509"); // this line is problem

        // SunX509 : supporting only: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
        kmf.init(ks, keyPassPhrase);

        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager(){
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                            throws CertificateException {

                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                            throws CertificateException {
                    }
                }
        },new SecureRandom());
        SSLSocketFactory factory = sc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket socket=null;
        try{
            //socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("XXXX",xxxx);/
            socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(ipAddress, Integer.parseInt(ports[portIndex]));

            //convert to array
            String[] cipherSelectedArray;
            if(isSupported == 1 ) {
                cipherSelectedArray = new String[] {msupportedcipherList.get(cipherIndex).trim()};
            }
            else {
                cipherSelectedArray = new String[] {mnotSupportedcipherList.get(cipherIndex).trim()};
            }

            String []mselectedSSLOrTLSVersionArrray = new String[] {mselectedSSLOrTLSVersion};   // if passing these --> getting connection timeout

            socket.setEnabledProtocols(mselectedSSLOrTLSVersionArrray);
            socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSelectedArray);
            for(int i = 0; i<cipherSelectedArray.length ; i++) {
                //System.out.println("ciphers are :" +  cipherSelectedArray[i]);
            }


            socket.setSoTimeout(15000);

            socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {

                @Override
                public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent event) {
                    ////System.out.println("completed");

                }
            });



            socket.startHandshake(); //handshake                                            as "SunX509" does not support SSL. I need to create above one. Can someone help.   And also with "SunX509" i am getting                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers problem with some ciphers. please help
```

Answer (score 8):

The parameter you are using `X509` is not recognized by the algorithm provider.

As described [getInstance(String algorithm)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/KeyManagerFactory.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) the reason is clear.

> NoSuchAlgorithmException - if no Provider supports a KeyManagerFactorySpi implementation for the specified algorithm.

The standard algorithms are described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)

I guess they support  `PKIX, SunX509` this two algorithm in `KeyManagerFactory`

So you have to use `SunX509` instead of `X509`.

[See the table here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SupportClasses)

Comment: Even if i use "PKIX" , there are some cihers with gives exception.              javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate). can someone help.

Comment: have you used `SunX509`?

Comment: yes. I used SunX509. at that with there are more exceptions. " javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)." while using "PKIX" less.

Comment: can somebody give one example for X509 for SSL connection.

Answer (score 3):

Read what the stack trace is telling you:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: X509 KeyManagerFactory not available

The `X509` algorithm is not available from the security provider you are using.  However, the following code should work for you:

```
final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
```

Please have a look at this [Code Ranch article](http://www.coderanch.com/t/133186/Security/Algorithm) which discusses your problem and also shows how to find out which security algorithms are available from your provider.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already used above code as you suggested. But SunX509 doesn't support SSl . It only support TLSv1,v2,v3. What i have to use if i want to create using SSL. please suggest.   One more issue if i use SunX509, it gives me exception. e.g. Cannot support TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers: what i have do to in that case.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the use of "SunX509" is that it is specific for an Oracle JRE and doesn't work in an IBM JRE, where the default is "IbmX509". A better solution which is vendor-agnostic is:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
```

The default algorithm is defined by the security property "ssl.keyManagerFactory.algorithm" in `<JRE_HOME>/lib/security/java.security`, and is by default "SunX509" in Oracle and "IbmX509" in IBM JREs (at least for Java 8).

Answer (score 0):

first check if needed algorithm is available in java.security of JDK jre
In my case I just changed the sequence of Algorithms and added a security provider in Java.security and it worked.

1. added security provides :

security.provider.12=sun.x.rsa.SunRsaSign

2. changed sequence of Algorithm :

From :

ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=SunX509

ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX

To

ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX

ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=SunX509

java.security path : \jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\security\java.security

Use below code to check if SunX509 algorithm is supported or not in you JDK

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String algorithm = "SunX509";
    Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunJSSE");

    if (provider != null && provider.getService("KeyManagerFactory", algorithm) != null) {
        System.out.println("SunJSSE provider supports the " + algorithm + " algorithm.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("SunJSSE provider does not support the " + algorithm + " algorithm.");
    }
}
```